# Trying to understand how to add my own classes within a namespace

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm new to using composer and was brought to my attention because of Rachet and websockets. I was able to get the Rachet websocket chat application working but now I want to use my own classes within the example.

I have the same directory structure as the chat example found [here](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) with these name changes:

`/src/MyApp/Chat.php = /src/Websocket/SocketControl.php`

`/bin/chat-server.php = /bin/socket-server.php`

My composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Websocket": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.3"
    }
}
```

In my `src` folder I've added a folder`MyClass` and have a file `Foo.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
class Foo{
    function __construct(){
        echo "Foo construct!\n";
    }
}
```

How am I able to get a new Foo in my SocketControler like for example:

```
<?php
namespace Websocket;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class SocketControl implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->foo = new Foo();
        echo "New construct!\n";
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You tell composer that the Websocket namespace is in the src directory. So if you set foo to namespace Websocket\MyClass, and try to use Websocket\MyClass\Foo it should work.

Comment: @JimL I'm not sure how to tell composer?

Comment: i moved the Foo class file into the Websocket fodler and set its name space to Websocket and that works, but I should understand why I couldnt access it in a different directory with a different namespace

Comment: It didn't have the correct namespace. If you have it in Websocket\MyClass you need to give it that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing is: Are you sure you understand how PHP namespaces work? Because autoloading is a different thing, and to first make things work, you might as well use the old fashioned `require_once()` to see if your code works or has some issues.

Autoloading itself should be pretty straighforward, but it will confuse you if you don't get your namespace issues straightened. The problem is not with the autoloading not working, but with your code requesting a class name that cannot be autoloaded because the class itself is named wrong.

For example, in your code, you are inside the namespace "Websocket" and have this code `new Foo()`. This will try to autoload the class `Websocket\Foo`. Do you have this class? No! You have `class Foo...`, but you didn't put `namespace Websocket;` as the first code line there.

Autoloading would tell you that PHP cannot load `Websocket\Foo`, but why? Your autoload definition is saying: Every class that starts with namespace `Websocket\` is in path "src/". So PSR-4 creates the path "src/Foo.php" to find `Websocket\Foo`. However, the code in that file does not declare such class! It declares `\Foo` in the global namespace. After executing that file, there is no class `Websocket\Foo` defined, and this will make the code fail.

Note that there is no direct connection between PHP namespaces and file system layout. In theory, you could have all kinds of namespaces spread over any kind of file layout. It was just for convenience reasons to choose the 1:1 mapping of class name to path name - it is not enforced by PHP nor guaranteed to work when autoloading code, i.e. a code file at the correct location still has to have the right code inside to hold true to it's promise to declare a class of the right name.